# Evitar que app se reinicie al presionar el launcher

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo una duda , acabo de terminar una app para android , hecha en android studio y escrita en Java , la duda que tengo es que al salir de la app y volver a entrar en ella presionando el launcher , se me reinicia , no se queda en segundo plano , si no que tal parece que la mata y por ende se reinicia , tengo un splash que es el que me sirve para poder evitar el intro cada vez que se cierra la app , guardo en SharedPreferences un boolean que me marca si la app se cerró por el usuario , (Se vuelve true en onBackPressed) , pero cada vez que la mando a segundo plano y vuelvo a presionar el launcher esta se reinicia completamente la aplicación sin borrarla de la pila de tareas y sin eliminarla directa de la pila , dejandome de lado las preferencias

```
    SharedPreferences 
    booleanC=getSharedPreferences("cerrar",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Boolean booleanCerrar=booleanC.getBoolean("cerrar",false);
```

Tambien tengo los metodos para el ciclo de vida de la app , pero no se ejecutan , tengo en onPause y el onResume en el cual reviso que no haya datos nuevos por recibir de mi servidor

```
   public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(!isOnline(getApplicationContext()) || !isOnlineNet())
    {

        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        int subrayado = Color.parseColor("#FFFFD600");
        fecha.setText("No tienes internet");
        fecha.setBackgroundColor(subrayado);
        meGusta.setImageResource(R.drawable.sinlike);
        meGusta.setEnabled(false);
        categoriaHai.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        likes.setText(" ");
        siHay2=true;
    }
    if(isOnline(getApplicationContext())&&siHay2 && isOnlineNet())
    {
        recreate();
        siHay2=false;
    }
    if(close)
    {
        recreate();
        close=false;
    }

}
```

> Y en el onPause solo comparo datos de mi servidor para que cada vez que se vaya a segundo plano , decidir si vuelve a tomar datos para setearlos o no
>
> El metodo recreate() solo se ejecuta cada vez que hay nuevos datos en el servidor y solo reinicia la activity en la que se setean los datos
>
> Lo de reiniciar la actividad desde 0 no sucede siempre , pero la mayoria de veces sí

Aclaro que esto no sucede cuando estoy ejecutando directo desde android studio  , solo sucecede cuando la app ya está publicada , se reinicia cada vez que la mando a segundo plano y vuelvo a presionar el Launcher , de antemano , gracias (:

**Agrego mi manifest**

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Hai"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    
    

 

    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label=" "
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:theme="@style/Normal">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"  />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Publicar"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
        android:label=" "
        android:parentActivityName=".main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Condiciones"
        android:label=" "
        android:parentActivityName=".Publicar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: El método recreate() realiza el reinicio?

Comment: No , el metodo recreate() solo hace que la activity se reinicie para volver a setear datos

Comment: me gustaría saber como estan configuradas tus Activity en tu androidmanifest.xml , usas android:noHistory ?

Comment: No , no uso android:noHistory , modifico la pregunta y te subo un acitivity de mi manifest (:

Comment: ok Rafa, gracias.

Comment: Listo Elenasys! (:

Comment: abres la Activity main desde splash mediante un intent? , main es la que se reinicia?

Comment: Sí , abro main desde un intent , lo que se reinicia es toda la aplicación cuando vuelvo a presionar el Launcher , como si la hubiera borrado de la pila de segundo plano :(  , lo raro es que no siempre sucede esto , a veces si y a veces no

Comment: si quitas todo lo que se encuentra en onResume() se reinicia también

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Quizás Android está destruyendo tu activity cuando la mandas a background?.
Si es así, mira en la documentación los métodos:

onSaveInstanceState
onRestoreInstanceState

En el primero salvas el estado de tu app, y en el segundo lo restauras.

Para testear, chequear en opciones de desarrollador > aplicaciones > no mantener actividades (de esta manera nunca guarda el estado de la activity)